# Python, grouping a large set of variables

Tags: python, variables, sum

I have the following example script with different values, my actualy xy list is much much bigger:

xy1 = value1
xy2 = value2
xy3 = value3
xy4 = value4
xy5 = value5
xy6 = value6
xy7 = value7
xy8 = value8
xy9 = value9

xytotal = sum((xy1, xy2, xy3, xy4, xy5, xy6, xy7, xy8, xy9))

The problem happens when I have thousands of these xy variables, it becomes tedious to add them all into the sum function.

Now is there a way to tell python to sum all xy values for each different xy (xy1, xy2, xy3 etc...)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not put them all in a list?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use separate variables. Use a list, maybe mixed with another data structure if your data is complex enough.

And while we're at it: [Variable names aren't data](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Assume Python throws your variable names away.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, yes you can declare a bunch of xy variables in a script and sum them:

```
xy1 = 1
xy2 = 2
xy3 = 3
xy4 = 4
xy5 = 5
xy6 = 6
xy7 = 7
xy8 = 8
xy9 = 9
xy10 = 10

cached = locals()
xytotal = sum(cached[k] for k in locals() if k.startswith('xy'))
```

Why you want to do this... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I should add, python has powerful builtin libs for inspecting and executing live source code:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html

You could parse the script as text and convert your variables into a list of values

Answer (score 0):

```
all_xy = [value1, value2, value3, ...]
# Note that xy_all[n-1] = valuen

xy_total = sum(all_xy)
```

If you wanted to grab them by using `all_xy[n] = valuen`, then you could use `all_xy = [0, value1, value2, value3, ...]`.

Using a list structure is definitely preferred in Python to using variable names, for one thing you can easily write list comprehensions, for example:

```
positive_xy = [ xy for xy in all_xy if xy>0 ]
positive_xy_total = sum(positive_xy)
```

*Another option would be to use a dictionary.*
.

Another reason to be aware of if you were checking `startswith('xy')` in `locals()` is you could easily try to sum "unexpected" variables, e.g. a function, which would cause a Python exception.